# Problem with constant autoloading in a Rails project (works occasionally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, nested, autoload

I am working with a Rails project and don't quite understand how Rails autoloading works in my particular case. I read some articles about Rails' autoloading and its pitfalls but those didn't really help me

I am building a processor for tasks (exercises). Each task has its custom processor class in `Tasks::<TaskName>::Processor` that mixes in module `Tasks::Processor` that contain shared code for task processors. Processors contain class `Get` (for processing GET requests) located in `Tasks::<TaskName>::Processor::Get` that mixes in `Tasks::Processor::Get` containing generic `Get`'s code.

I've simplified the code a little bit so it's easier to understand and removed all the business logic but it's still enough to reproduce the problem.

**So the problem is:**

when I run `Tasks::TaskOne::Processor.new.get` it works fine, but if I run `Tasks::TaskTwo::Processor.new.get` after that it throws an error: *NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Tasks::Processor::Get:Module*. It also works the other way round: if I run TaskTwo's processor's code first then it works fine but the TaskOne's processor will throw the error. It just fails to find the specific implementation of Get and instead finds the generic module and tries to instantiate it which is obviously impossible.

Here is the code together with the structure.

Shared code:

*app/models/tasks/processor.rb*:

```rb
module Tasks

  # generic Processor (mixed in by custom processors)
  module Processor
    # ...
  end
end
```

*app/models/tasks/processor/get.rb*:

```rb
module Tasks
  module Processor

    # generic Get
    module Get
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

TaskOne's code:

*app/models/tasks/task_one/processor.rb*:

```rb
module Tasks
  module TaskOne

    # processor for task_one
    class Processor
      include Tasks::Processor # mix in generic task processor

      def get
        Get.new.call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*app/models/tasks/task_one/processor/get.rb*:

```rb
module Tasks
  module TaskOne
    class Processor

      # task_one's processor's custom Get
      class Get
        include Tasks::Processor::Get # mix in generic Get

        def call
          puts "in task_one's Processor's Get"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And practically identical code for the TaskTwo:

*app/models/tasks/task_two/processor.rb*:

```rb
module Tasks
  module TaskTwo

    # processor for task_two
    class Processor
      include Tasks::Processor # mix in generic task processor

      def get
        Get.new.call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*app/models/tasks/task_two/processor/get.rb*:

```rb
module Tasks
  module TaskTwo
    class Processor

      # task_two's processor's custom Get
      class Get
        include Tasks::Processor::Get # mix in generic Get

        def call
          puts "in task_two's Processor's Get"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It has most likely something to do with Rails' autoloading, because when I use plain ruby and manually require all the files and try to run the code the problem doesn't happen.
Could you, please, explain why it works like this and tell me what the best way to avoid this problem is? Seems like Rails doesn't like the fact that I have a class and a module with same name and it gets confused, but I thought it shouldn't be a problem as they are in different namespaces.
I could have just named the generic class something different, but I'd really like to understand why using the same class name for both specific implementation and generic one only works for the first thing to load but not for the next. Thank you very much for your help!

P.S. my version of Ruby is 2.5.1 and Rails version is 5.2.1

Comment: The files will be required in the order of their hierarchy. If you have a file which depends on another which is at the same depth, you might need to explicitly load it first (maybe in application.rb?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was literally reading about autoloading yesterday. Your problem is the same as the one outlined here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#when-constants-aren-t-missed

Basically, any time you write `Get.new.call`, you need to be more specific. It doesn’t know which `Get` to use in the tree of possible `Get`s. The first time you call it, it hasn’t had to load up more than one `Get` class, and so it actually finds the right one. After that call, you’ve now auto loaded MORE classes, and now things start to get dicey. You need to either qualify your `Get` to be more specific, and/or use `require_dependency` to force the right classes to be loaded in. However given your case, I think `require_dependency` will just make it fail every time, since you’ll now have all of the classes loaded up.

Comment: I tried being specific (writing "Tasks::<TaskName>::Processor::Get.new.call" inside the processors' code) and I still get the same error (undefined method `new' for Tasks::Processor::Get:Module) -- I even tried changing my code so generic Processor and Get are classes instead of modules and tried inheriting them instead of mixing in -- same result, error persists. While require_dependency has actually helped (without being specific with Get in Processor).

Comment: I start to hate Rails autoloading. Whole day wasted on this problem and still don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: But your answer was very helpful to me anyway, thank you for pointing me to the code with the problem similar to mine.

Comment: Are you using a Ruby version that’s less than 2.5? I know 2.5 changed a bit about how constants (and classes) are looked up. So using 2.5+ may make your life easier if you aren’t already.

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.5.1 :)

Comment: Ahh. Oh, one thing you _might_ be able to do is `self::Get.new`. Since `self.get` is a class method, `self` refers to the current processor class. So that may be a way for you to use inheritance to get the appropriate `Get` class without writing the whole thing out each time in each class.

Comment: I suppose you meant "self.class::Get.new"? Unfortunately it doesn't help either. Same error like before. What I have finally done in the the real application in production is just renamed module Task into GenericTask and renamed module Task::Get into GenericTask::GenericGet so Rails doesn't get confused. (: I will still try to understand what exactly goes on with this code though when I have more free time -- I just can't sleep properly until I understand these tiny little things that can just suddenly come and bite me at any time. :D

Comment: Oh you’re right. I don’t know why I thought `self.get` is a class method. Glad you have things working!